# Почему удаляется первый элемент в этом двусвязном линейном списке?

Tags: c++, структуры

Когда пытаюсь удалить элемент в ДЛС, то удаляется выбранный элемент и 1 элемент в списке, не понимаю, в чем проблема. C++

```
//Дана последовательность неповторяющихся чисел , ,… и
//некое число c, принадлежащее данной последовательности.
//Составить 2 последовательности.Первая – все числа, находящиеся
//до указанного числа в обратном порядке.Вторая – все числа после
//указанного числа в прямом порядке. Двусвязный линейный список
#include <iostream>
struct list
{
    int number; // поле данных
    struct list* next; // указатель на следующий элемент
    struct list* prev; // указатель на предыдущий элемент
};
struct list* init(int a) // а- значение первого узла
{
    struct list* lst;
    // выделение памяти под корень списка
    lst = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    lst->number = a;
    lst->next = NULL; // указатель на следующий узел
    lst->prev = NULL; // указатель на предыдущий узел
    return(lst);
}struct list* addelem(list* lst, int number)
{
    struct list* temp, * p;
    temp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    p = lst->next; // сохранение указателя на следующий узел
    lst->next = temp; // предыдущий узел указывает на создаваемый
    temp->number = number; // сохранение поля данных добавляемого узла
    temp->next = p; // созданный узел указывает на следующий узел
    temp->prev = lst; // созданный узел указывает на предыдущий узел
    if (p != NULL)
        p->prev = temp;
    return(temp);
}
struct list* deletelem(list* lst)
{
    struct list* prev, * next;
    prev = lst->prev; // узел, предшествующий lst
    next = lst->next; // узел, следующий за lst
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        next->prev = NULL;
        free(lst);
        return(next);
    }
    else
    {
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = lst->next; // переставляем указатель
        if (next != NULL)
            next->prev = lst->prev; // переставляем указатель
        free(lst); // освобождаем память удаляемого элемента
        return(prev);
    }
}
void listprint(list* lst)
{
    std::cout << "Текущий список:" << std::endl;
    struct list* p;
    p = lst;
    do {
        std::cout << p->number << std::endl; // вывод значения элемента p
        p = p->next; // переход к следующему узлу
    } while (p != NULL); // условие окончания обхода
}
struct list* findElem(list* first, int index)
{
    list* p;
    p = first;
    if (index != 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return first;
    }
    return p;
}
struct list* sequence(list* first, int c) //Создание первой последовательности
{
    std::cout << "Первая последовательность – все числа, находящиеся\n"
        "до указанного числа в обратном порядке.";
    struct list* temp, * p; //Временный указатель
    temp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    //Выделение памяти под временный элемент списка
    p = first;//Присвоение временному указателю ссылку на первый элемент
    while (p->number != c)
        p = p->next;
    p = p->prev;
    bool is_first = true;
    do {
        if (is_first)
        {
            temp = init(p->number);
            is_first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            addelem(temp, p->number);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        p = p->prev;
    } while (p != first);
    addelem(temp, p->number);
    while (temp->prev != NULL)
        temp = temp->prev;


    return (temp);
}
struct list* sequence1(list* first, int c) //Создани второй последовательности
{
    std::cout << "Вторая последовательность – все числа, находящиеся\n"
        "после указанного числа в прямом порядке."; struct list* temp, * p; //Временный указатель
    temp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    //Выделение памяти под временный элемент списка
    p = first;//Присвоение временному указателю ссылку на первый элемент
    while (p->number != c)
        p = p->next;
    p = p->next;
    bool is_first = true;
    int i = c;
    do {
        if (is_first)
        {
            temp = init(p->number);
            is_first = false;
            i = p->number;
        }
        else
        {
            addelem(temp, p->number);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        p = p->next;
    } while (p->next != NULL);
    addelem(temp, p->number);
    do
    {
        temp = temp->prev;
    } while (temp->number != i);
    return (temp);
}
void showmenu()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Введите цифру для продолжения:" << endl;
    cout << "1.Отобразить список" << endl;
    cout << "2.Добавить элемент списка." << endl << "3.Удалить элемент списка";
    cout << endl << "4.Отобразить 1 последовательность" << endl;
    cout << "5.Отобразить 2 последовательность" << endl << "6.Выход" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    list* elem1 = init(1);
    addelem(elem1, 423);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    addelem(elem1, 12);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    addelem(elem1, 43);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    addelem(elem1, 64);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    addelem(elem1, 76);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    addelem(elem1, 54);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    addelem(elem1, 9);
    elem1 = elem1->next;
    while (elem1->prev != NULL)
        elem1 = elem1->prev;
    listprint(elem1);
    cout << endl;
    showmenu();
    int vybor;
    while (cin >> vybor && vybor != 6)
    {
        switch (vybor)
        {
        case 1:
            listprint(elem1);
            break;

        case 2:
            int val;
            cout << "Введите значениe добавляемого элемента: " << endl;
            cin >> val;
            cout << endl;
            addelem(elem1, val);
            listprint(elem1);
            break;
        case 3:
            int index;
            cout << "Введите порядковый номер элемента, который"
                "вы хотите удалить (кроме первого) : " << endl;
            cin >> index;
            cout << endl;
            //list* h = findElem(elem1, index);
            elem1 = deletelem(findElem(elem1, index));
            listprint(elem1);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Введите число с, принадлежащее данной последовательности,"
                << endl << "до которого отобразить последовательность 1: ";
            int c;
            cin >> c;
            cout << endl;
            listprint(sequence(elem1, c));
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Введите число с, принадлежащее данной последовательности,"
                << endl << "до которого отобразить последовательность 2: ";
            int c2;
            cin >> c2;
            cout << endl;
            //listprint(sequence1(elem1, c2));
            listprint(sequence1(elem1, 423));
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Глаза разуй тут всего 6 пунктов меню!" << endl;
        }

        showmenu();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы в одном случае возвращаете следующий, во втором предыдущий. А когда вызываете, то началу списка назначаете или предыд или след. Теряете все до этого. Уберите возвращаемое значение, передавайте адрес адреса начала списка. Когда надо исправляйте это начало.

```
void deletelem ( list * lst , struct list * * begin )
{
    struct list* prev, * next;
    prev = lst->prev; // узел, предшествующий lst
    next = lst->next; // узел, следующий за lst
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        next->prev = NULL;
        free(lst);
        * begin = next ;
        // return(next);
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = lst->next; // переставляем указатель
        if (next != NULL)
            next->prev = lst->prev; // переставляем указатель
        free(lst); // освобождаем память удаляемого элемента
        //return (prev);
        return ;
    }
}

..

//elem1 = deletelem(findElem(elem1, index));
deletelem(findElem(elem1, index), & elem1 ) ;
```